# The SafeAreaView causes weird gap on screen

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, safeareaview

I'm starting to get some weird gaps on my screens in my React Native application.

I have simplified a screen so you see the issue here:

```
<SafeAreaView style={{flex:1, backgroundColor: 'yellow'}}>
    <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'green'}}>

    </View>
</SafeAreaView>
```

When I enter the background-mode and reopen the app (quickly swipe gesture on iPhone 12) the issue has disappeared. See example:

[image: Weird gap in bottom of screen]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue might be with the conflicting SafeAreaView in the Navigation component.
You can skip the bottom padding for the SafeArea like this,

```
import {SafeAreaView} from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
```

```
<SafeAreaView
  edges={['right', 'top', 'left']}
  style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'yellow'}}>
    <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'green'}}></View>
</SafeAreaView>
```

OR for functional component with Hooks

```
import { useSafeAreaInsets } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
```

```
const insets = useSafeAreaInsets();
```

```
 <View
   style={{
     paddingTop: Math.max(insets.top, 16),
     flex: 1,
     backgroundColor: 'yellow',
   }}>
   <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'green'}}></View>
 </View>
```

for more details on `react-native-safe-area-context` APIs [here](https://github.com/th3rdwave/react-native-safe-area-context#api)

Comment: Hey ImKrishh and thank you for a fine reply :-)

I think you are right about the conflicting navigation and safeaareaviews. I tried your first suggestion and everything works like a charm with react-native-safe-area-context and no bottom edges. 

I accepted your reply as an answer for my issue and you've earned the bounty ;-)